# Is there any way into the Abandoned Hebra Mine forge construct tower?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

In the Abandoned Hebra Mine, on top of the forge construct tower there is some unusual smoke coming out of the chimney. Is there any way into this tower? Or is there nothing more to it?

> I've defeated Master Kohga and found the chest with the 20 crystallized charges on top of the tower already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way into the tower. There is nothing more to it.

Comment: After checking the details on this and other towers, and trying to detect chests in the area, this seems like the most likely scenario. Thanks!